Intermittent ECONNRESET errors in TCP communication between NestJS applications on K8s
We are encountering an issue when deploying NestJS applications on K8s. We have two NestJS applications, A and B, which communicate with each other via TCP. We use Cluster IP services to config these apps's networks and they can connect with each other via services's name
However, we've observed that after a certain period, the connection from A to B fails with an ECONNRESET error. But if we attempt to reconnect immediately afterward, it works again.
We think that the issue might be related to the TCP keep-alive configuration in Kubernetes, but we haven't been able to investigate further. We also tried Node Port services to connect directly via node's ip instead of services's name, but the error still happens.
Do you have any idea?

Was App A or B deployed at that time?

@xirehat, both were running and there was no new deployment

Kubernetes does not have any keep-alive configuration in service level. When the issue is persisted in NodePort service too It's better to look TCP keep-alive configuration in node level like net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time
